# Fixed div size independent of screen size

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to achieve an effect contrary to that promoted with flexbox. I have a 3x3 div layout and I want the center div to stay fixed in the middle of the screen and the 8 divs around it to be shown only in part (this is, if the set of 9 divs is larger than the screen).
As far as I could investigate, flexbox always brings solutions to avoid this effect, and I want to provoke it.
Is there a css command to keep this design fixed in the center so that it is not deformed, and its size is independent of the screen size?

Answer (score 0):

use css  `max-width:250px;` or `width:250px;` with css media query
refer link [https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_width.asp][1]